# Specific date comparison

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Lets say I have an document like this:

```
{
    productName: 'soap',
    expiredDate: ISO_DATE_FORMAT
}
```

In normal sql I can query like this:
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Month(expiredDate) = 11`.

How to achieve it in mongoDB or mongooseJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the aggregation framework which has some operators that you can use. Consider the first use case which looks at manipulating the [date operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) within the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline and a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline to filter documents based on the additional field with the **[`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month)** expression:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "productName": 1,
            "expiredDate": 1,
            "expiredMonth": { "$month": "$expiredDate" }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "expiredMonth": 11 } }
])
```

---

Another option is using a single pipeline with **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** operator which incorporates the functionality of **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** and **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** as above and returns all documents which match a specified condition using **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** system variable and discards those that don't match using the **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** system variable. Keep in mind this operator does a collection scan so the first pipeline option may be optimal:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$eq": [
                        { "$month": "$expiredDate" }, 
                        11
                    ]
                }, 
                "$$KEEP", 
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: seems working. I will learn the aggregation framework first, and then applied it for my use case. Because actually my use case a little bit different than this example.

Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation framework

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project : {month  : {"$month" : $expiredDate},productName : 1,expiredDate:1},{$match : {month : 11}}])
```